# How do I keep connection in object explorer

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

This is regarding SQL server 2008 management studio..

I connect to different environment DB and every time I launch the Sql management console, I have to sign up every time to get those connections back in object explorer. Is there a way I could persist the connection so I don't have to login every time to different environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register the servers, type CTRL + ALT + G, add the server you want and next time, go to registered servers, right click the one you want and select new query

Answer (score 0):

As @SQLMenace said, you can register the servers.
Look at View -> Registered Servers option.